# How to store user location

Tags: users

I use [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module to track user location with option IPInfoDB.com. But as I understand Smart IP does not store by default user location in database. Is there any option to configure this or I need to make own module? Ultimately I need to show user who is in the same city or region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Smart IP is solely for IP geolocation, it doesn't not touch storage of user location addresses.

Depending on your needs, [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) (with the User Location submodule) or a combination of [GeoField](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/geofield)/[Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) on your a profile (you might want to guess the location while letting the user determine what his address) will get your location storage needs.

None of those modules have Smart IP integration so you'll have to build some custom code to add IP geolocation to either of those storage options.